# Cross-platform file sharing

Tags: web-apps, cross-platform, file-sharing

File sharing software with the following characteristics:

- Works on most platforms
- Lossless media sharing
- May require internet connection, but only to discover devices
- Fast transfer speeds
- No GPS, Bluetooth or WiFi required
- Open source
- Private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Snapdrop](https://snapdrop.net/) has these characteristics. It is a web app, so, it can work on almost all new platforms.

Comment: That's two answers.  Please post them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just setting up an HTTP server, and then you can use the files via their URLs. If you're using media files, you might try using mpv to stream those URLs (or playlists of them). See [my answer to another question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83502/offline-music-player-for-androids-without-ads/83513#83513) for details about how to use mpv on the command-line on Android (the mpv site has information about other ways to run it).

No Internet would be required, but you would need a local network. You could use CAT6 cables instead of WiFi.

mpv is open-source and [cross-platform](https://mpv.io/installation/), and the HTTP server's platform wouldn't matter.

Or, if you don't like http, I imagine ftp might work. I haven't tested ftp addresses on mpv, though.

Comment: I don't understand what is the relation between a media player and file sharing software?

Comment: You mentioned lossless media sharing (which seems to indicate you'd be streaming it, otherwise why mention the fact that it's lossless?), so I figured that needed to be covered in the answer. FTP and HTTP servers cover everything else.

Comment: You're right, I meant that it doesn't compress image files or videos, sends them just like normal files.