# Android 6 compatible music player with queueing

Tags: android, audio-player

I run a small android phone (with a 2.5 inch screen) as a music player.

While the phone itself is *perfect* - I've not really found a music player I like. Foobar2k's android port comes close - but it won't let me queue up music.

So my requirements are

- Runs on android 6 (and frankly the phone is mostly offline so if its an 'older' less supported player with the rest of my requirements I'm good). There's very few options on the size range, and this device does what I need perfectly.
- can handle a large music collection from an SD card - I've about 10k songs of various formats including Flac, MP3 and WMP
- I need a searchable playlist of *all* tracks - I mostly play random music and sometimes decide I want a song. Foobar2000 does this ok
- Need to be able to queue up tracks to play *next* and be able to do so with multiple tracks. The *desktop* foobar2k does this, but not the mobile one. I think the *old* google play music did too.
- Needs to be usable on a smaller screen. I don't need *perfect* - but if its something with a busy busy UI, Its going to be a pain.

Comment: Hi. Have a look at this previous answer, to see if recommendations can help you: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83502/offline-music-player-for-androids-without-ads/  e.g. Musicolet, VLC, etc

Answer (score 1):

I use **[Folder Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.folderplayer&gl=US)** on Android and I think it has all the features you are looking for.

- I have all my music on SD card and it works fine
- I have them in folders, and it can play a folder sequentially or randomly.
- Its free

> About this app
>
> Already organized your music in folders? Folder Player gives you direct access to your audio library since 2010 :)
> Folder Player is FREE (NO Ads, NO in-app purchases!), minimalistic but powerful alternative music player which uses folders to play music or audiobooks. Supports MP3, as well as (*IF* supported by your hardware), FLAC, WAV, AAC among others.
> Play directories the same way you play individual audio tracks.

[image: Screenshot]